# Cyrillic text validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm currently trying to validate 2 textboxes on C# for first and last names respectively but the catch is the text needs to be in Cyrillic. This is what I have so far

```
string expression = "^[\u0410-\u042F][\u0430-\u044f]{2-20}$";

if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, expression) && 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox2.Text, expression))
    MessageBox.Show("Correct",""); 
else 
    MessageBox.Show("There was a mistake in the names.", "Error");
```

The first letter of each name should be a capital, and every other is a lowercase, hence the Unicode for Cyrillic for capitals and lowercases. Like this, it gives me the "else" option and I've no idea where the mistake might be.

Comment: Note that your names now have to be a minimum of _three_ characters (one uppercase, and two lowercase). So Dutch people named Ян or the Asian Mr. Ву are out of luck. Always be careful when restricting name entry fields, unless you know _exactly_ who your audience will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `{2-20}` to `{2,20}`

> {n,m}
>
> Matches at least `n` and at most `m` times. `n` and `m` are nonnegative integers, where `n <= m`. There cannot be a space between the comma and the numbers.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's always the simplest things, isn't it? Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of trouble.